# Flutter : correct way to call "nested future"

Tags: flutter, nested, future, setstate

What is the best way to call nested future in Flutter ? Or flutter in general ?

In my app, I have to get the *current user* (which have its data in `final storage = new FlutterSecureStorage();`.

From this user, I call an API which is by the *user id*. Theses two parts works fine independently (quite slow, but that's another story).

On many screen, I have to call **asynchronious functions**, I do this by using `Future.delayed`, while my coworker is used to use something like this :

```
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getCurrentUser();
  }

  void getCurrentUser() async {
    user = await UserAuth.getCurrentUser();
  }
```

this is my nested Futures. I need the current user to be loaded on my initState to load my publications. I have to get the user inside this because it can also be the not current user (this function will be used to retrieve current user but also other users publications).

```
class _UserPublicationsState extends State<UserPublications> {
  List<Publication> listPublications;
  List<Widget> list = [];
  User user;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () async {
      await UserAuth.getCurrentUser().then((value) {
        setState(() {
          user = value;
          UserWS.getPublicationsPerUsers(user).then((value) {
            setState(() {
              listPublications = value;
            });
          });
        });
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (listPublications == null) {
      return FullPageLoading();
    }

    String title = "title";

    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: getSimpleAppBar(context, title),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: getSavedPublications(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: 1. I don't understand what "call nested future" means.  You *await* `Future`s.  Waiting for a `Future` might involve internally waiting for intermediate `Future`s, but that's an implementation detail that the waitee needs to be concerned with. 2. It's not clear at all why you're using `Future.delayed`. If it's just to create an `async` function, that's not very useful. 3. You usually should just use `FutureBuilder`.  Also see: [What is a Future and how do I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63017280/)

Comment: 1) By nested, I understand "future depending on another future result". 
2) I'm using `Future.delayed` because that's how I've learned to use future. 
3) Can I use 2 FutureBuilder in a raw?

Comment: 2. Using `Future.delayed` to deal with an existing `Future` makes no sense.  Why not use a `Future.delayed` to use the `Future` returned by `Future.delayed`?  Why not have infinite calls to `Future.delayed`?  3. I don't understand what "in a raw" means.

Comment: 2) I don't understand, can you show me any example ? 3) By in a raw, I mean : first, get the user; second; take that user to call another future method

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what is your approach but you can put your futures in a list inside Future.wait()

like this:

```
Future.wait([
      Future.delayed(Duration.zero),
      Future.delayed(Duration.zero),
    ]);
```

if you mean that a future is depending on another future you should use the .then() after the future call

like this:

```
Future.delayed(Duration.zero).then((value) => Future.delayed(Duration.zero));
```

I hope this is what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in comments, waiting for a "nested `Future`" isn't any different than waiting for any other `Future`.  Suppose you have:

```dart
Future<String> fetchDataFromServer() async {
  var firstPart = await fetchFoo();
  var secondPart = await fetchBar();
  return '$firstPart $secondPart';
}
```

A caller would just need to do, say, `print(await fetchDataFromServer());`.  It doesn't matter that `fetchDataFromServer` internally waits for some other `Future`s. `fetchDataFromServer` returns a `Future<String>` that indicates when the operation is complete.  The caller does not need to know nor care whether that operation involves other asynchronous sub-operations or not.

> I'm using `Future.delayed` because that's how I've learned to use future.

`Future.delayed` itself returns a `Future`.  If you think you need to use `Future.delayed` to use a `Future`, then the logical conclusion would be:

```dart
var future = fetchDataFromServer();
var future2 = Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () async => await future);
var future3 = Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () async => await future2);
var future4 = Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () async => await future3);
// Ad infinitum.
```

Typically you'd use `Future.delayed` to actually introduce a delay, often to treat an a synchronous operation as an asynchronous one for testing or for demonstrative purposes.  If you have an existing `Future` already, then wrapping it with `Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () => await existingFuture)` is pointless.  Just use `existingFuture` directly.

Finally, using `await` is syntactic sugar for setting up a `.then()` callback.  Mixing both `await` and `.then()` is inconsistent at best and confusing at worst.

```dart
await someFuture.then((value) => doSomething(value));
```

is equivalent to:

```dart
var value = await someFuture;
doSomething(value);
```

Putting the above together, your code:

> ```dart
> @override
> void initState() {
>   super.initState();
>   Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () async {
>     await UserAuth.getCurrentUser().then((value) {
>       setState(() {
>         user = value;
>         UserWS.getPublicationsPerUsers(user).then((value) {
>           setState(() {
>             listPublications = value;
>           });
>         });
>       });
>     });
>   });
> }
> ```

is equivalent to:

```dart
Future<void> _updatePublications() async {
  var currentUser = await UserAuth.getCurrentUser();
  setState(() {
    user = currentUser;
  });

  var publications = await UserWS.getPublicationsPerUsers(user);
  setState(() {
    listPublications = publications;
  });
}

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();

  _updatePublications();
}
```

Note that with the simplified version, it's more apparent that you might want to combine the two `setState` calls so that you rebuild your widget only after `user` and `listPublications` have both been updated.